# Existe um modo de colapsar todos os blocos de código em eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Eu tenho arquivos gigantes com muitos blocos de código, atualmente sei que ao apertar +- expande ou colapsa o bloco atual, alguém sabe como fazer para expandir ou colapsar todos de uma vez no Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim existe por default é: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd>.

Podes mudar este atalho em:  `Window` -> `Preferences`,  e procura por "Keys" depois por "Collapse All".

E para abrir todos os blocos o default é: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
 <kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um atalho, mapeado por default para <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd> (tecla divisão no teclado numérico).

Você pode alterá-lo para alguma outra coisa via Window -> Preferences, busque por "Keys", em seguida por "Collapse All".

Para abrir todos os blocos o atalho é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd> (tecla multiplicação no teclado numérico).

Na extensão do Eclipse *PyDev*, fechar todos os blocos é 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>

Para abrir todos os blocos, é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

(Traduzido do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1726525/2241463)).